# Memory crash with ABNewPersonViewController using ARC

Tags: iphone, ios, automatic-ref-counting, abaddressbook

I have faced problem when I using `AddressBook` framework (Core Foundation) which make memory crash for a `NSMutableDictionary` variable using to set phone number and another fields in address book such as email below. This case happen as a first time when I call this method passing the data into `ABNewPerson` after that when cancel or save contact and come back to my view controller and click another time to call this method give me error on phone number data in `NSMutabledictionary` may code is below:

```
 ABNewPersonViewController *newPersonViewController =[[ABNewPersonViewController alloc]init];
 newPersonViewController.newPersonViewDelegate = self;
 UINavigationController *newNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]

                                                       initWithRootViewController:newPersonViewController];
 newPersonViewController.displayedPerson =(ABRecordRef)[self buildContactDetails];
 [self presentModalViewController:newNavigationController animated:YES];


 - (ABRecordRef)buildContactDetails {
      ABRecordRef person = ABPersonCreate();
      CFErrorRef  error = NULL;

     // firstname
     ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, (__bridge_retained CFTypeRef)(self.name.text), NULL);

    // lastname
    NSString *regionName = self.region.text;
    ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty, (__bridge_retained CFTypeRef)(regionName), NULL);


    //Phone

    ABMutableMultiValueRef phoneNumberMultiValue =  ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABPersonPhoneProperty);
    //Here is the problem this release dictionaryDetail after come back another time
    NSString *phoneNumber = [[dictionaryDetail valueForKey:@"selectedRow"] valueForKey:@"phone" ];
    NSLog(@"NNNNN %@",phoneNumber);

    ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phoneNumberMultiValue,(__bridge CFTypeRef)(phoneNumber) ,  kABOtherLabel, NULL);
    ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
    ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty, phoneNumberMultiValue, nil);
    //CFRelease(phoneNumberMultiValue);



    // Start of Address
    ABMutableMultiValueRef address = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiDictionaryPropertyType);
    NSMutableDictionary *addressDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    NSString *subRegion = self.subRegion.text;
    [addressDict setObject:@"" forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStreetKey];
    [addressDict setObject:@"" forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressZIPKey];
    [addressDict setObject:subRegion forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressCityKey];

    ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(address, (__bridge_retained CFTypeRef)(addressDict), (__bridge CFStringRef)(AMLocalizedString(@"Hospital", @"Hospital")), NULL);
    ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonAddressProperty, address, &error);
    //CFRelease(address);
    // End of Address
    if (error != NULL)
       NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

   return person;
}
```

And here the crash :

```
 [CFString release]: message sent to deallocated instance
```

Comment: did u put the breakpoint and find where the error occured?

Comment: Yes , i do it the problem in this dictionary (dictionaryDetail) which is release from ARC may be after i open address book view controller and dismissed it

Comment: it give me data on first view but after that crashed

Comment: I want to notice that this dictionary is passed to this view controller by didSelectRow from table view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved , the problem in the phone ABMutableMultiValueRef  correct answer is below :

Previous answer :

```
   ABMutableMultiValueRef phoneNumberMultiValue =  ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABPersonPhoneProperty);
```

Correct Answer :

```
  ABMutableMultiValueRef phoneNumberMultiValue =  ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);
```